# How can I exclude a Base class from serialization process of struts json

Tags: java, json, inheritance, serialization, struts2

I can serialize the properties upto Base Class (2 Levels) in the following way.

```
public class BaseRoot{
 String prop1; //getter and setter
}

public class SubClass extends BaseRoot{
 String prop2; //getter and setter
}

public class ActionClass extends SubClass{
 String prop3; //getter and setter
}
```

In struts json I can serialize all the properties using

```
<result type="json">
 <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param> //This will allow parent to be serializable
 <param name="excludeProperties">price,description</param> //Exclude parameters
</result>
```

But I just want to serialize classes ActionClass and SubClass. I do not want to serialize BaseRoot and other classes extending by BaseRoot class. I know that I can exclude properties. But I want to exclude a whole class from serializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the default functionality.

You would need to write your own result type, or possibly serializer, which you might be able to plug in to either the existing or a new result type–not sure which would be easier.

That said, I find the design/need for this a little sketchy–perhaps you want a Presenter, Decorator, Facade, etc. instead of trying to hack around concrete classes.